# Fallback Database with Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql, h2

do someone of you know a way to have 2 Databases running parallel? 
We are using Hibernate 4 and as a main database Postgres 9.3 - this db is hosted on another machine then the application - if the database is down we still have to save some stuff.

So first intention was to write it into a csv, but I'm not a friend of writing stuff into an unordered file. So I want just to use a fallback Database (thinking of H2 Database). Does someone has experience with such a construct?

We are also using Spring 4 - I would just set up another datasource + sessionfactory + transactionmanager - and add the name at the @Transactional method to use the right manager. any other ideas?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend the Spring [AbstractRoutingDataSource](http://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/) and configure two actual data sources:

1. a primary PostgreSQL data source
2. a secondary H2 data source

The application logic will see only one data source, which is the router which will decide which data source is going to switch to on demand.

When the primary data source is down you need to instruct the router to pick the fall-back H2 one.